# google app engine : query geohash

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a db.StringProperty() of geohash, by given a hashcode, how do I find the closer 10 result?

I tried below but doesn't seem to be right

```
pois = POI.all().filter('geohash <', h_latlng).order('-geohash').fetch(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geohash cannot accomplish the task to find the n-nearest results. You can find the contents of any square region by prefix. But to find a reliable result containing the n-nearest you need to fetch at least 9 prefixes, making it a quite expensive query. Complicating the matter is that prefixes of the 9 squares need to be calculated.

IMO this problem is currently a hard problem to solve efficiently on app-engine. So far, I am on it since a year and have not found a sophisticated and fast solution. A Relational DB with geo index or 2 inequalities will perform such tasks better and faster. But I am interested in good solutions, too. :-)

Citation David Troy:

> Geohash also has the property that as
>   the number of digits decreases (from
>   the right), accuracy degrades.  This
>   property can be used to do bounding
>   box searches, as points near to one
>   another will share similar Geohash
>   prefixes.
>
> However, because a given point may
>   appear at the edge of a given Geohash
>   bounding box, it is necessary to
>   generate a list of Geohash values in
>   order to perform a true proximity
>   search around a point.  Because the
>   Geohash algorithm uses a base-32
>   numbering system, it is possible to
>   derive the Geohash values surrounding
>   any other given Geohash value using a
>   simple lookup table.

See: https://github.com/davetroy/geohash-js

Comment: Why 9? You can start with the smallest square covering the point of interest and expand from there. The number you have to fetch depends on how dense points are around that point, though.

Comment: 9 (or maybe just 4) actually already assumes that you know a "zoom" level that holds enough data and that your data is uniformly distributed. If you don't it is much worse.The problem are border cases: If you query p=(lat,lng)=(0.001,-0.001) and have 100 POIs in London with lng > 0 and none with lng < 0. Your query point hashes at (binary) 00* and your data is at 01* How would you approach that?

Comment: Right, so if it's near a corner you might need 4, but not 9. I think your assumptions are extremely optimistic, too. :)